# How to show single entry in list view from SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have created a database in SQLite that get the employee information from a form containing edit texts and I want to show the the name of the employee in a listview in another activity, and when I click the a single name I want my app to show the complete information in the next activity, kindly help me to make the list view and and get the names from the database and make it clickable that opens the complete information of the emloyee.

Here is the code
This is my InformationDataBase Adapter class

```
public class InformationDataBaseAdapter {

    public static final String ID_COLUMN = "id";
    public static final String NAME_COLUMN2 = "name";
    public static final String FNAME_COLUMN = "fname";
    public static final String EMPLOYEE_DOB = "dob";
    public static final String EMPLOYEE_INTEREST = "interest";
    public static final String EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String EMPLOYEE_CONTACT = "contact";

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "information.db";
    static final String EMPLOYEE_TABLE = "employee";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;




    static final String CREATE_EMPLOYEE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + EMPLOYEE_TABLE + " (" + ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + NAME_COLUMN2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + FNAME_COLUMN + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + EMPLOYEE_INTEREST + " TEXT, "
            + EMPLOYEE_DOB + " DATE, " + EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS + " TEXT, " + EMPLOYEE_CONTACT + " INTEGER );";


    public SQLiteDatabase db;
    private final Context context;
    private DbHelper dbHelper;

    public InformationDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) {
        context = _context;
        dbHelper = new DbHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public InformationDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        db.close();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance() {
        return db;
    }

    public void insertEntry(String Name, String FName, String Interest ,String DOB,String Address,String Contact) {
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put("NAME", Name);
        newValues.put("Fname", FName);
        newValues.put("Interest", Interest);
        newValues.put("DOB", DOB);
        newValues.put("ADDRESS", Address);
        newValues.put("CONTACT", Contact);

        db.insert("EMPLOYEE_TABLE", null, newValues);

    }

    public int deleteEntry(String Name) {

        String where = "NAME=?";
        int numberOFEntriesDeleted = db.delete("INFORMATION", where,
                new String[] { Name });
        return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
    }

    public String getSinlgeEntry(String Name) {
        Cursor cursor = db.query("EMPLOYEE", null, " NAME=?",
                new String[] { Name }, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() < 1) // UserName Not Exist
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String info = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("INFO"));
        cursor.close();
        return info;
    }

    public void updateEntry(String ID, String Name, String FName, String Interest ,String DOB,String Address,String Contact) {
        ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();

        updatedValues.put("NAME", Name);
        updatedValues.put("Fname", FName);
        updatedValues.put("Interest", Interest);
        updatedValues.put("DOB", DOB);
        updatedValues.put("ADDRESS", Address);
        updatedValues.put("CONTACT", Contact);;

        String where = "NAME = ?";
        db.update("INFORMTION", updatedValues, where, new String[] { Name });
    }
}
```

And this is my Database helper class

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public DbHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(LoginDataBaseAdapter.DATABASE_CREATE);
    db.execSQL(InformationDataBaseAdapter.CREATE_EMPLOYEE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TEMPLATE");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

And this is the java class of information form activity

public class Information extends Activity {

```
TextView Tv1,Tv2,Tv3,Tv4,Tv5,Tv6,Tv7;
EditText Etname,EtFname,Etinterest,EtDOB,EtAddress,EtContact;
Button Bsubmit;

InformationDataBaseAdapter informationDataBaseAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.information);

    informationDataBaseAdapter=new InformationDataBaseAdapter(this);
    informationDataBaseAdapter=informationDataBaseAdapter.open();

    Tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.InfoTV1);
    Tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.InfoTV2);
    Tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.InfoTV3);
    Tv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.InfoTV4);
    Tv5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.InfoTV5);
    Tv6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.InfoTV6);
    Tv7=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.InfoTV7);
    Etname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.InfoET1);
    EtFname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.InfoET2);
    Etinterest=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.InfoET3);
    EtDOB=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.InfoET4);
    EtAddress=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.InfoET5);
    EtContact=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.InfoET6);
    Bsubmit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bsubmitInfo);

    Bsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Name=Etname.getText().toString();
            String FName=EtFname.getText().toString();
            String Interest=Etinterest.getText().toString();
            String DOB=EtDOB.getText().toString();
            String Address=EtAddress.getText().toString();
            String Contact=EtContact.getText().toString();

            // check if any of the fields are vaccant
            if(Name.equals("")||FName.equals("")||Interest.equals("")||DOB.equals("")||Address.equals("")||Contact.equals(""))
            {

                        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(Information.this);
                        alertBuilder.setTitle("Invalid Data");
                        alertBuilder.setMessage("Please, Enter valid data");
                        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                   dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        });
                        alertBuilder.create().show();

            }
            else
            {
                // Save the Data in Database
                informationDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(Name,FName,Interest,DOB,Address,Contact);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Information successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               Intent i2= new Intent(Information.this,Menu.class);
                startActivity(i2);

            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    informationDataBaseAdapter.close();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's need a lot of code. I want to give you my vision of program structure. Anyway you have to work by yourself to do what you want.

1. Working with database in Android should be through ContentProvider https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html. Here is developer guide https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html but I think, you should download some project from github and look how it works. Clone all code from here https://github.com/bazli/android_packages_apps_AlarmClock/blob/donut/src/com/android/alarmclock/AlarmProvider.java and modify.
2. To load data from database use CursorLoader https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html. About Loaders you can read here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html.
3. Use SimpleCursorAdapter https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html to handle data from database and show it in ListView
4. I think, it's to early for you to use fragments, so you so you just have to start new Activity after user click on some item in ListView

Hope it helps! Good luck!